# How to click all button on Prometheus's target web page

Tags: prometheus

In our Prometheus session, we have many many targets. Sometimes I need to (un)fold all targets whats means to click on every `show more` / `show less` button. Manually. What's not effective.

Is there a way how to:

1. click on all buttons with the name `show more` or `show less`?
2. save this solution to the browser (i.e. to Bookmarks) and invoke it when you need it?

I inspected the Prometheus web page and the element with the button looks:

```html
<h2 class="job_header">
  <a id="job-blackbox-1-1-1-1-probe" href="#job-blackbox-1-1-1-1-probe">blackbox-1-1-1-1-probe (13/13 up)</a>
  <button type="button" class="targets btn btn-primary expanded-table">show less</button>
</h2>
```

Who is working with Prometheus - understand me.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of Prometheus (2.2.26) has redesigned UI. In the Targets section is now the toggle button enabling *Expand/Collapse All*. Finally. :)